# Custom dataset in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I have some images and their respective labels as a training set.

I want to use it as a dataset in TensorFlow (as how we use the mnist dataset and can get data in batches using mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE))

The question is, How do I make my own dataset so that I can use it in batches ?

Additional Info:
The training set have 4575 images of 28 x 28 (scaled) and the classification labels. There are a total of 62 classes.

[image: Data_Info]

Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.data.from_tensor_slices(tf.convert_to_tensor(np_images), tf.convert_to_tensor(np_labels))` to create a dataset consisting (image, label) pairs. Now you can apply `.batch(BATCHSIZE)` function on this which will create batches of size you want. 
Then you can just directly feed this to the model function like `.fit()` if using `tf.keras`.

For more info., go through following links-

[from_tensor_slices](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices)

[convert_to_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)

[batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch)